# Hashmap with two key object having same value but different bucket index

Tags: java, hashmap

If Hashmap has two keys having same value, for eg:

```
HashMap map=new HashMap();
map.put("a","abc");
map.put("a","xyz");
```

So here put two key with "a" value and suppose for first bucketindex=1 and
second bucketindex=9

So my question is if bucket index for both is coming different after 
applying hashing algorithm, in this how to handle for not inserting 
duplicate key as it is already present and hashmap cannot have duplicate 
key.
please suggest your view on this.

Comment: So please define "bucketindex"

Comment: Bucket Index - "Each bucket has a unique number - that's what identifies the bucket."

Answer (score 2):

There won't be any such thing as "second bucket index".

I suggest you add something like `System.out.println(map.toString())` in order to see what that second put() has done to your map.

EDIT:

In the method `put(key,value)`, the "bucket index" is computed as a function of the `key` element's value, not the `value` element's value (so "a" and "a" give the same index for the bucket).  This function is supposed to be deterministic so feeding it the same value ("a" in your case), the same hashCode() will come out and subsequently, the same bucket index.

Comment: if i have String key1="a" and String key2="a" now the hashcode value can be different as it is calculate on the basis of object and suppose hashing is giving different bucket index and there is possibility of getting different value .

Comment: That is why classes can override the implementation of hashCode(), and effectively must do so for them to be usable as a key in a HashMap.  The String class effectively does that.  Don't do that, and all sorts of crazy things (collecitvely known as "unpredictable results") will start to happen.

Comment: PS In addition, hashCode() must be implemented such that it is "consistent with equals" in some sense : if x1.equals(x2) returns true, then x1.hashCode() and x2.hashCode() must return the same value.  Also note that there are some more ways to cause crazy things happening, e.g. to make that portion of the state mutable that hashCode() is based upon.

Answer (score 1):

In Java if a hashing function returns the same hash, equality of two objects is determined by `equals()` method. And if the objects are found equal, the old one is simply replaced by the new one.

Instead, if the objects are not equal, they just get chained in a linked list (or a balanced tree) and the map contains both objects, **because they are different**.

So, back to your question: "if bucket index for both is coming different after applying hashing algorithm" - this is impossible for equal objects. Equal objects **must** have the same hash code.

Comment: how hashcode value is generated ,like native method generate hashcode value for any object?

Comment: @RahulMahajan It's not generated, it uses the default hashCode() method of java.lang.Object. If you want to implement your hash function, you just have to override hashCode() method and provide your hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

To make @Erwin's answer more clear, here's the source code of `HashMap` from JDK

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
}

static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

Digging more deep you will find that the bucket index is calculated from `key`'s hash code.

To make it simple and straightforward, putting duplicate key with different values to the same `HashMap` will result just one single entry, which the second put is just overwriting the value of the entry.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to create a hashmap that can handle more than one value for the same key, what you need is a Map> so it adds a new value to the arraylist everytime the key is the same.